# iFrame no supported when creating a synthetics test

Tags: datadog

I'm trying to create a Browser test for my website using Synthetics but I'm getting the following error in the recording moment: Your website does not support being loaded through an iframe.

How can I enable my website to be used in the iframe format?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried opening the site in a popup? Here are some [troubleshooting docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/synthetics/troubleshooting/#the-website-is-not-loading-in-the-iframe) for Synthetics Monitoring that might help.

Comment: Hi, Eric! How's it going? I didn't even noticed that button, my mistake. That did the trick, thanks so much for your help! :)